# list.append() doesn't keep shuffled values

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I have the following code:

```
list =[] 
list1 = ['Dublin', 'Kiev', 'Warsaw', 'Moscow']

for i in range(3):
    random.shuffle(list1)
    list.append(list1) 
list
```

However, the output keeps the last shuffled value as:

```
[['Dublin', 'Moscow', 'Kiev', 'Warsaw'],
 ['Dublin', 'Moscow', 'Kiev', 'Warsaw'],
 ['Dublin', 'Moscow', 'Kiev', 'Warsaw']]
```

I'm really not sure what's happening, and why it behaves this way.
Appreciate any replies.

Comment: Did you mean to write: ‘list.append(list1[:])’?

Comment: obligatory advice: don't name a variable `list`.  Shadowing builtins is bad.

Comment: Yeah, I should use mylist, the post was just for example.

Answer (score 4):

You are appending the reference of the shuffled list, so after 3 iterations you have appended the same reference to the list. since shuffle modifies the list in place and all 3 references point to the same list, then the last shuffle is what all of them will see.

If you want to store the different versions of the shuffle you could append a copy / slice of the list on each shuffle

```py
from random import shuffle

mylist =[]
list1 = ['Dublin', 'Kiev', 'Warsaw', 'Moscow']

for i in range(3):
    shuffle(list1)
    mylist.append(list1[:])
print(mylist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
['Dublin', 'Warsaw', 'Kiev', 'Moscow'], 
['Kiev', 'Dublin', 'Warsaw', 'Moscow'], 
['Kiev', 'Moscow', 'Dublin', 'Warsaw']
]
```